# Give each tab a different color in Semantic UI React Tab Module?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I would like to give each tab a different color.
Similar to [this](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#menu-variations-colored-inverted) except a different color for each tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how to do this.

```
const panes = [
    {
      menuItem: {
        content: 'Tag 1',
        color: 'teal'
      },
      render: () => <MyComponent />}
  ];
```